# How to filter views "node-changed-day is not node-created-day"

Tags: views, datetime

I want to list node posts so, that only those ones will display which node-updated day is not the same as node-creaded day but at least next day or newer. How to filter it in Views? I'm using Drupal 6.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution myself. There is  available ”Views PHP Filter” module for Drupal6. After installing I added new filter:  ”Node: Node ID PHP handler” for my Views. I left the filter options as default but filled PHP– textarea vith code below, and it worked.

```
$nodeids = array();  

$result = db_query(db_rewrite_sql('SELECT DISTINCT(c.nid) FROM {node} c  WHERE c.status = 1  AND  c.changed >= c.created + 86400  - c.created % 86400  ORDER BY c.changed DESC'));

while ($node = db_fetch_object($result))  {
$nodeids[] = $node->nid; 
};

return $nodeids;
```